# How to display the selected value from an autocomplete textfield in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, autocomplete, material-ui

Newbie to react here and I am building a search page in a multi-form app where users can search for a student with first name, last name or student ID in an autocomplete textfield.

Now, options for the autocomplete textfields are successfully passed and are displayed once the cursor is in the textfield but typing or actually selecting a value doesn't seem to affect the value of the textfield.

Code below

```
<Autocomplete
        id="auto-complete"
        options={values.suggestions}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.stuId+" "+ option.fName+" "+option.lName}
        autoComplete
        includeInputInList
        fullWidth
        renderInput={params => (
           <TextField {...params}  margin="normal" fullWidth />)}
        />
```

values are passed through props.

Intended outcome is for the 'searchKeyword' in state to be updated with the stuId of the student selected and for the autocomplete textfield to display it. is there an onChange or default value function I could use?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```js
<Autocomplete
  ...
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={(event, value) => this.setState({ value })}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: something similar i believe. 
I've tried 
```
value={values.searchKeyword}
onChange={handlechange('searchKeyword')}
```

Comment: would you like to share the code how you're doing that?

Comment: this is my handleChange function
```
handleChange = input => e => {
  this.setState({[input]: e.target.value});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value inside option state in hooks

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [option, setOption] = useState("");
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top10Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      value={option}
      onChange={(e, v) => {
        setOption(v);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top10Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 }
];
```

refer to this codesandbox
[image: Edit restless-meadow-hj0em]